# Mint Authority Being a Signer

Tags: anchor, metaplex, mint, authority, upgrade-authority

I am getting error: `Instruction does not support native tokens` when trying to initialize a new SPL metadata via:

```
 // Invoke the create_metadata_account_v3 instruction on the token metadata program
        create_metadata_accounts_v3(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.to_account_info(),
                CreateMetadataAccountsV3 {
                    metadata: ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
                    mint: ctx.accounts.mint_token.to_account_info(),
                    mint_authority: ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(), // <=============== This line fails when signer is used, mint_token PDA doesn't fail
                    update_authority: ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
                    payer: ctx.accounts.signer.to_account_info(),
                    system_program: ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                    rent: ctx.accounts.rent.to_account_info(),
                },
            )
            .with_signer(signer_seeds),
            DataV2 {
                name: name,
                symbol: symbol,
                uri: uri,
                seller_fee_basis_points: 0,
                creators: None,
                collection: None,
                uses: None,
            },
            true, // is_mutable
            true, // update_authority_is_signer
            None, // collection_details
        )?;
```

anyone can help explain why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably if you create it with_signer the authority needs to be the pda from the seeds.
Can you try without?

Here is an example on how to create meta data in a program:
https://beta.solpg.io/tutorials/battle-coins

Comment: I think you are right. with signer requires mint_token pda. thank you!